# Swift 3.0 Today Extensions Compact Mode with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I created today extension widget.
I have a problem with the lover versions of iOS.

If the Mode is set to Compact then the height is always set to 110,
but I found one widget in my list of widgets, where there is an widget with compact mode, with big height and without show/hide button.

I am uploading image.

Can someone tell me how is it possible to do?

I tried all the examples, but nothing works.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0aY4.png)

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0aY4.png

Comment: @SophieGairo Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In **iOS 10**

1. You can remove the `Show Less/Show More` button from `Today's Widget` by setting `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` to `compact`, i.e.

   ```
       self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .compact
   ```
2. `Widget` height in `Compact` mode is `110`. You cannot increase/decrease that.

Comment: Did you saw my image?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .compact` in `viewDidLoad` and then you can set custom size in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
let customSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 300)
preferredContentSize = customSize
```